# Stack Overflow employer sign up button shows <svg> HTML tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, stack-overflow-talent, sign-up

I have noticed that the sign-up button for employers on the [SO login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) shows the `<svg>` HTML tag instead of the actual button image.

I tried refreshing my page, going to incognito mode in Chrome and also another browser (Edge), so just wanted to report it here. PFA the screenshots as well.

Chrome Browser Incognito mode

[image: Chrome Incognito mode]

Below screenshot is from Edge browser.

[image: MS Edge browser]

Comment: Looks like the tags have been converted. `Sign up on Talent &lt;svg aria-hidden=&quot;true&quot;.....`

Comment: Oh no, &#x6e;&#x6f;&#x74;&#x20;&#x74;&#x68;&#x69;&#x73;&#x20;&#x61;&#x67;&#x61;&#x69;&#x6e;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recently changed the way we include our Stacks-Icons dependency and that change caused the raw HTML for an icon to be rendered as a string.

We've shipped a fix to production, so the problem should be resolved. Thank you for reporting this issue, Sammy J!

Answer (score 1):

Been this way for a few days now and I am not in incognito mode.

Using Chrome for Mac Version 110.0.5481.77

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is still present - Chrome 103 on Win7.